# Listview adapter implementation issue

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a data structure that contains parents CLAIMS. and Children EXPENSES.

it looks like this:(visual representation, not actual fact.  need idea on how to implement)
claim list = {claim1, claim 2, claim 3,....)

claim 1:(name + claim 1 expense list), claim 2:(name + claim2 expense list),
ArrayList = {CLAIM1, CLAIM2, CLAIM 3......}

claim constructor:

```
public void Claim(String name, Date date){
     this.name = name;
     this.date = date;
     ArrayList<Expense> expList = new ArrayList<Expense>();
}
```

the expense constructor:

```
public void Expense(String name, Date date){
     this.name = name;
     this.date = date;
}
```

CLAIM AND EXPENSE are obviously different objects with their own attributes.
the above is just the representation of each claim object in my program.

each claim is constructed with a name and expense list.  I have created an adapter for the claims, so I can see them.  what I want to do now is create an adapter that allows me to click on a specific claim and it will give me a listview of that claims's expense list.
 I have looked at all kids of examples and cannot find something similar.  is there any ideas on what to do>

Comment: Using expandable listview is better option here, create a custom expandable list adapter and implement the logic.

Comment: thank you. i will look into creating one